# lifterlms certificate verification

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I am trying to learn lifterlms. I need to build a function/option where employer/3rd party can check verify a certificate by using the certificate no. If successful, it should show course title, candidate name and awarding date. I could use mysql query but lifterlms's table and fields are very complicated. is there any lifterlms user who could give the some guidance how to get those information. Please notify, I am not asking you to write some codes for me, I just need some guidance only on how it can be done. thanks